# What is Container-Based Authentication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, authentication, containers

I know the "XMLHttpRequest" object supports a method "open" which has an optional parameter of a username and password. I just found out that these parameters can be supplier for requests requiring container-based authentication.

This is the method signature:

```
open(method, url, async, username, password)
```

Can someone help me out with the meaning of Container-Based Authentication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Container-Based means that the container of the web application (e.g. tomcat, jboss, etc.) performs the authentication, and makes the results of the authentication known to your web application.

As a consequence, your web application doesn't need to implement NTLM, HTTP Basic, or any authentication code, because the container already does all that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please highlight the difference between Container-Based and (NTLM, HTTP Base). In terms of implementation. Please.

Comment: Thats a difference between "where" the authentication occurs, and "how" the authentication happens. That's not really comparable.

Comment: Thank you once more. As i may guess, Container-Based is more like a configuration and the rest are done by programming.